# Wait for all threads in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm using the construct "thread" in C++ and I create a variable number of thread in a recursive function. I want the main thread to wait for all of them. How can I do it without WaitForMultipleObjects ?

Comment: Store them in a [container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) and wait for them in a loop? Using [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) there's really no other way. if you want to be portable and standards compliant.

Comment: I tried to put them in a vector but, when I do the push_back method, Visual Studio says that threads are not copyable

Comment: @user3671840 you can smart pointers instead of the threads - e.g `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::thread>>`

Comment: @user3671840 can you post your code and the exact compiler error?

Comment: @user3671840: But threads are movable. So if you use a variable for the thread, you have to call `threads.push_back(std::move(my_thread));`

Comment: I did the error to install Visual Studio in Italian so I think that you can't understand the error if I post it, however for now I solved by creating a vector<thread *>

Comment: @user3671840 I mentioned the pointers because if you have the thread bound to a class instance that has a noncopyable member you will have an error. Can you at least show if the thread function is a class function or not? And if yes, how does the class look. And don't use plain pointers, wrap the thread pointer in a `unique_ptr`.

Comment: If you share **why** do you want to do it without waitformultiple object, I might help.

Comment: I didn't want to use waitformultipleobject because I want to do my program portable. However I had to create the thread directly when I do push_back and not before, this was my (stupid) error

Answer (score 35):

Take a look at [example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/thread/) in cplusplus. Store threads with emplace_back() in vector. At the end you have loop with joins.

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads;
//create threads
for (int i=1; i<=10; ++i)
    threads.emplace_back(std::thread(increase_global,1000));
//wait for them to complete
for (auto& th : threads) 
    th.join();
```

Comment: Not my vote, but it's generally less accurate than cppreference.com.

Comment: Agreed that cppreference.com is more accurate, but no example for vector<thread> :-(

Comment: cplusplus.com has shaped up considerably. Downvoting an answer for referring to it _is not_ constructive. Calling out specifics that are actually wrong with cplusplus.com _is_ constructive.

Comment: `emplace_back` is probably better here.

Comment: @Johann: Well, let's see. Unnecessary global mutable state? Check. Pointless member function? Check. Terrible (and pointless) inheritance from a Standard class? Check. Using older `bind` mechanics instead of lambdas? Check. Even the for loops are strange being 1-indexed instead of 0-indexed. They can't even write a simple numerical `for` loop.

Comment: @Puppy: Thanks for the concrete examples. While I agree on some of them, I saw nothing strange with the `for` loops. You claim "They can't even write a simple numerical `for` loop", yet I fail to find the blatant error in it that you seem to have found.

Comment: Hi the vector will grow indefinitely right? What if the program is a long running one such as web server?

Comment: @DachuanHuang in case of web server you may create fixed number of working threads depend on the number of CPUs and assign clients to threads in round robin. You can go for different collection as needed. Initial question was how to gracefully join threads. Confuse about the long running web server. Assuming you may have created threads dynamically on connections. I would reconsider as it's prone to DoS attacks.

Answer (score 5):

Use an atomic variable as a counter, increase the variable when launching new thread, in the thread decrease the counter once the thread is completed.

```
int main() {
    mutex m;
    condition_variable cv;
    atomic<int> counter = 0;

    // .... in your recursive call
    // increase counter when launching thread.
    counter++;
    thread t([](){
        // do whatever
        lock_guard<mutex> lk(m);
        counter--;
        cv.notify_all();
    });
    t.detach(); // no need to join anymore.
    // .... end recursive call

    unique_lock<mutex> lock(m);
    cv.wait(lock, [](){ return counter == 0; });
}
```

Comment: And add the overhead of polling (which is done by some of the `condition_variable.wait()` implementations) to the solution?

Comment: @mg30rg condition variable is blocking not polling, thread join is also blocking.

Comment: does counter need to be atomic?  it's guarded by m.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that there is an unavoidable race condition -- consider what happens if the thread gets pre-empted off of the CPU immediately after the call to `cv.notify_all()`, but before the thread has actually stopped running.  In that case, the main-thread code will momentarily act as if the thread is gone, when in fact it is still present.  Calling `join()` is the only way for the main thread to guarantee that the child thread is *really* gone.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner you're right, however, at the moment notify_all is sent, the thread has no more work and I suppose it will exit as soon as CPU gets it back to execution. When the motivation to wait for sub threads is to avoid them hanging forever, this should work. M.L.'s answer should be the accepted answer though.

Comment: One way to handle the race condition would be to add code to the main thread so that when it sees the value of the atomic counter is zero, it calls `join()` on all spawned threads at that time.  Since (barring a bug in the program), the counter would only be zero if all threads were already either exited or on the verge of exiting, it would be safe to assume that the calls to `join()` will all return quickly, and after they have returned, the main thread would know for sure that all child threads are fully exited.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [boost thread_group](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.threadgroup).  It only works with boost threads, but they have a nearly identical interface to std::thread (boost threads were the basis for threads in the standard library in C++11), and once you add all your threads to the thread_group, you simply call join_all on the group.  You could also implement a thread_group class of your own, to work with std::thread, which would essentially do what has already been suggested, with a vector of thread objects or pointers, and waits on them in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the specifics of your situation but this kind of approach might be useful to you:

```
using thread_vec = std::vector<std::thread>;

void batch_process(int n)
{
    static std::mutex mtx;
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    std::cout << "process: " << n << '\n';
}

void recursive(thread_vec& tv, int n)
{
    // do some stuff
    tv.emplace_back(batch_process, n);

    if(n > 0)
        recursive(tv, n - 1);
}

int main(int, char* argv[])
{
    thread_vec tv;

    recursive(tv, 3);

    for(auto&& t: tv)
        t.join();
}
```

**Output:**

```
process: 1
process: 0
process: 2
process: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler!?

Use a simple atomic global counter:

```
using namespace std;

atomic_ullong numThreads = 0;
```

At start of thread function's:

```
numThreads++;
```

In all return from thread function's:

```
numThreads--;
```

Waiting:

```
while (numThreads)
{
    Sleep(100);
}
```

There is a tiny flaw here, if wait loop starts before any thread function has incremented.
This could be eliminated by wait for an event after creating threads, signaled after the increment.

Comment: Why not use something standard like `std::atomic`?

Comment: And yes std::atomic is even simpler !

Comment: @GunnarNilsson compiler is free to assume `numThreads` is a `const` and change the loop to `while(true)` if you don't explicitly use atomics TBH.

Comment: No, since compiler should see the inc/dec's. 
(Another case, I've seen, is when and address was only modified by hardware, we hade to declare it volatile, to not be optimized away.)